lmer (lme4) nested random structure gives singular fit
I'm running the following model on some reaction time data:
m_EDSIT_GV_noENGvars <- afex::lmer(RTlog ~ Version * (age + latent_var_nor_proficiency + Nback_score) + Version * poss_domain * Language_group + (1+Version|Item) + (1+Version|Language) + (1+Version|Language:Participant_Private_ID), data=SPR_EDSIT_noENGvars_GV, control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),(calc.derivs = FALSE))

And I'm getting a singularity warning, which seems to be caused by the inclusion of the random effect for Language, rather than the complexity of the model per se, because even if I make the model super simple, I get the warning only when I include Language, but not when I leave it out.
Some background information about the data: My main variable of interest is the interaction between Version, poss_domain, Language_group. I'm controlling for the effects of age, latent_var_nor_proficiency and Nback_score interacting with Version.
There are three Language_groups:

ITASPA, which consists of Languages: "Spanish" and "Italian";
DUTENG, consisting of Language "Dutch" and "English";
TUR, which only contains language Turkish (I initially thought this was the problem, but I have the same issue when I remove Turkish altogether)

I'm interested in the differences between Language_groups, above and beyond any potential differences between the individual languages within the groups. Therefore, I want to include Language as a random effect, and since participants are nested within languages (i.e. each participant only belongs to one language), I included it like this in the code above:
(1+Version|Language) + (1+Version|Language:Participant_Private_ID), 

but I've also tried:
(1+Version|Language/Participant_Private_ID)

as well as including them separately:
(1+Version|Language) + (1+Version|Participant_Private_ID)

But the issue remains.
This what the random effects output looks like. The corr. for Language is NaN, which seems to confirm this is where the problem lies.
Random effects:
 Groups                          Name        Variance              Std.Dev.      Corr 
 Language:Participant_Private_ID (Intercept) 0.0788530881838231668 0.28080792044      
                                 VersionGV   0.0045642641055289347 0.06755933766 0.19 
 Item                            (Intercept) 0.0008356029770342042 0.02890679811      
                                 VersionGV   0.0009195357201974827 0.03032384738 -0.75
 Language                        (Intercept) 0.0000000000000000000 0.00000000000      
                                 VersionGV   0.0000000000000001909 0.00000001382  NaN 
 Residual                                    0.1166423533975448623 0.34152943270      

Does this mean it is impossible to include Language as a random factor when Language_group is in the model? Do you have any suggestions how to test the effect of Language_group while controlling for differences between Languages within each group?
Thanks a lot in advance for any suggestions!

Brief thoughts- first.  are all those random slope necessary?  They are expensive in terms of model complexity.  Second, can youndrop (1+Version|Language) and just use (1+Version|Language:Participant_Private_ID)?   This won't respect the nesting, but should simplify the model

Another brief comment - it's usually not recommended to use a variable with only 3 levels as a random effect grouping variable, you may want to consider using Language as a fixed predictor instead.

@NBrouwer: thanks a lot for your reply! 1) Yes, they are. My main effect of interest is not reactions times per se, but the effect with which people slow down in version 2 relative to version 1. 2) This works, the warning disappears! But I'm not sure whether this code does what I want it to do? To clarify: each participant only pertains to one Language, and I want to allow for variation both between languages and between participants within languages.

@Sointu. Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify: language has 5 levels: Dutch, English, Italian, Spanish, and Turkish. They are grouped into 3 Language groups: DUTENG, ITASPA and TUR. About your suggestion: if I use Language as a fixed effect, it will correlate very strongly with Language_group, right? Since DUTENG only has Dutch and English and ITASPA only has Italian and Spanish, and TUR only has Turkish. So, that wouldn't work, would it?

No that wouldn't work,sorry I read carelessly. But modeling Language_group as fixed and Language as random effect when they are derivatives of each other may actually be (one) reason for singularity, they use up a lot of same variance. How many observations do you have?

Also re. The random slopes - is Version a categorical variable?  How many levels are there, and do all subjects experienc5all versions?   Ideally you could allow the effect of Version to between eg subjects, but in my experience it's hard to include categorical random "slopes" in complex experimental designs with limited sample size

@Sointu, yes that was my worry also. I have 18699 observations.

@Nbrouwer: Version is a categorical var with 2 levels, and all subjects experience both. The inclusion of Version in and of itself does not really seem to be the problem, because the model converges if I leave out the RE of Language.
